# Screen goes black on laptop (Debian stretch + cinnamon)

Tags: debian, cinnamon, intel-graphics

I recently installed Debian stretch (testing) on a new laptop (dell xps 13 with touchscreen) with the cinnamon desktop environment. For the Intel Graphics I use `xserver-xorg-video-intel`. When I logged in, the screen would turn off (no backlight, no pixels) after a few seconds (most of the time). I realized it was probably an issue with both systemd and cinnamon picking up the "lid open/close" events, so I modified `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` as follows:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=ignore # Modified for black screen issues
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
```

This way only cinnamon is responsible for the lid events. Still, every now and then, my screen goes off (this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the login, though I have to close the lid to "restart" the screen). There doesn't seem to be anything wrong in `Xorg.conf`, but I could be wrong. Here's Xorg.log:

```
[     2.704] 
X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
[     2.704] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     2.704] Build Operating System: Linux 4.1.0 x86_64 Debian
[     2.704] Current Operating System: Linux nicolas-dell-xps-13 4.1.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.1.6-1 (2015-08-23) x86_64
[     2.704] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.1.0-2-amd64 root=UUID=972389a1-8070-4b50-b09e-7a8f94ab3445 ro quiet
[     2.704] Build Date: 11 August 2015  10:51:15AM
[     2.704] xorg-server 2:1.17.2-1.1 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
[     2.704] Current version of pixman: 0.33.2
[     2.704]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     2.704] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     2.704] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Oct  2 16:43:37 2015
[     2.705] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     2.707] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     2.707] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     2.707] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     2.707] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     2.707] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     2.707] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     2.707] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     2.707] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     2.708] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     2.708]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     2.710] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[     2.710] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     2.710] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     2.710] (II) Loader magic: 0x5632ff691d40
[     2.710] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     2.710]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     2.710]    X.Org Video Driver: 19.0
[     2.710]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[     2.710]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[     2.711] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     2.714] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:1616:1028:0665 rev 9, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[     2.715] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     2.715] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     2.721] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.721]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     2.721]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[     2.721] (==) AIGLX enabled
[     2.721] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[     2.722] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[     2.722] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[     2.722] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[     2.722] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[     2.722] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     2.722] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[     2.722] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[     2.725] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.725]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 2.99.917
[     2.725]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     2.725]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[     2.725] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     2.725] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[     2.725] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.725]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.17.2
[     2.725]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     2.725]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[     2.725] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     2.726] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     2.726] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.726]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.4.4
[     2.726]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     2.726]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[     2.726] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     2.726] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     2.726] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.726]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.3.3
[     2.726]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     2.726]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[     2.726] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[     2.726] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[     2.726] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[     2.726] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[     2.726] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[     2.726] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     2.726] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     2.726] (++) using VT number 7

[     2.739] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20150327
[     2.739] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917-2 (Vincent Cheng <vcheng@debian.org>)
[     2.739] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[     2.739] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[     2.740] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     2.740] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     2.740] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     2.740] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     2.741] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.741]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 0.0.2
[     2.741]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[     2.741] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[     2.741] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD graphics 5500
[     2.741] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx, avx2
[     2.741] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[     2.741] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     2.741] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[     2.741] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     2.741] (II) intel(0): Output eDP1 has no monitor section
[     2.741] (--) intel(0): Found backlight control interface intel_backlight (type 'raw') for output eDP1
[     2.741] (II) intel(0): Enabled output eDP1
[     2.741] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 has no monitor section
[     2.741] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1
[     2.741] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[     2.742] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[     2.742] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[     2.742] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[     2.742] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[     2.742] (--) intel(0): Output eDP1 using initial mode 3200x1800 on pipe 0
[     2.742] (==) intel(0): TearFree disabled
[     2.742] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[     2.742] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[     2.742] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     2.742] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[     2.742] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[     2.742] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[     2.742] (II) Module "present" already built-in
[     2.742] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[     2.742] (II) Unloading modesetting
[     2.742] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[     2.742] (II) Unloading fbdev
[     2.742] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[     2.742] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[     2.742] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[     2.742] (II) Unloading vesa
[     2.742] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[     2.744] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Broadwell backend
[     2.744] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[     2.744] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[     2.744] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[     2.744] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[     2.745] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[     2.745] (==) intel(0): display hotplug detection enabled
[     2.745] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[     2.745] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[     2.745] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: i965
[     2.745] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[     2.745] (II) intel(0): hardware support for Present enabled
[     2.745] (--) RandR disabled
[     2.749] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[     2.795] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[     2.795] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[     2.795] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[     2.796] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile
[     2.796] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[     2.796] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
[     2.796] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[     2.796] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[     2.796] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[     2.796] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
[     2.796] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[     2.796] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[     2.804] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 3200x1800@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[     2.825] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 846 x 476
[     2.865] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event4)
[     2.865] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     2.865] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[     2.866] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[     2.867] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.867]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 2.9.2
[     2.867]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[     2.867]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[     2.867] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[     2.867] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[     2.867] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[     2.867] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[     2.867] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[     2.867] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[     2.867] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input5/event4"
[     2.867] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[     2.867] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     2.867] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     2.867] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     2.868] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event8)
[     2.868] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     2.868] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[     2.868] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[     2.868] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event8"
[     2.868] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[     2.868] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[     2.868] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[     2.868] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input10/event8"
[     2.868] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[     2.868] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     2.868] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     2.868] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     2.868] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[     2.868] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     2.868] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[     2.868] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[     2.868] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[     2.868] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[     2.869] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[     2.869] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[     2.869] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input3/event2"
[     2.869] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[     2.869] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     2.869] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     2.869] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     2.869] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event1)
[     2.869] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     2.869] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     2.869] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event3)
[     2.869] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     2.869] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Sleep Button'
[     2.869] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[     2.869] (**) evdev: Sleep Button: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[     2.869] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x3
[     2.869] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Found keys
[     2.869] (II) evdev: Sleep Button: Configuring as keyboard
[     2.869] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input4/event3"
[     2.869] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[     2.869] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     2.869] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     2.869] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     2.870] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event11)
[     2.870] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     2.870] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     2.870] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event12)
[     2.870] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     2.870] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     2.870] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event13)
[     2.871] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     2.871] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     2.871] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ELAN Touchscreen (/dev/input/mouse1)
[     2.871] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     2.871] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     2.871] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Digital PCBeep (/dev/input/event6)
[     2.871] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     2.871] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     2.872] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic (/dev/input/event7)
[     2.872] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     2.872] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     2.872] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN (/dev/input/event10)
[     2.872] (**) DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[     2.872] (**) DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: Applying InputClass "Multitouch Touchpad"
[     2.872] (**) DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[     2.872] (**) DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[     2.872] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[     2.872] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[     2.872] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.872]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.8.2
[     2.873]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[     2.873]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[     2.873] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN'
[     2.873] (**) DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: always reports core events
[     2.873] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event10"
[     2.939] (II) synaptics: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: found clickpad property
[     2.939] (--) synaptics: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: x-axis range 0 - 1216 (res 12)
[     2.939] (--) synaptics: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: y-axis range 0 - 680 (res 12)
[     2.939] (II) synaptics: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: device does not report pressure, will use touch data.
[     2.939] (II) synaptics: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: device does not report finger width.
[     2.939] (--) synaptics: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: buttons: left double triple
[     2.939] (--) synaptics: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: Vendor 0x6cb Product 0x76ad
[     2.939] (--) synaptics: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: invalid pressure range.  defaulting to 0 - 255
[     2.939] (--) synaptics: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: invalid finger width range.  defaulting to 0 - 15
[     2.939] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[     2.939] (--) synaptics: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: touchpad found
[     2.939] (**) DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: always reports core events
[     2.960] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/INT3433:00/i2c-1/i2c-DLL0665:01/0018:06CB:76AD.0001/input/input12/event10"
[     2.960] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 10)
[     2.960] (**) synaptics: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[     2.960] (**) synaptics: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[     2.960] (**) synaptics: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.144
[     2.960] (**) DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[     2.960] (**) DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[     2.960] (**) DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     2.960] (**) DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     2.961] (--) synaptics: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: touchpad found
[     2.961] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN (/dev/input/mouse0)
[     2.961] (**) DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[     2.961] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event0)
[     2.961] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     2.961] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[     2.961] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[     2.961] (**) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[     2.961] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Vendor 0x1 Product 0x1
[     2.961] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Found keys
[     2.961] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[     2.961] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0/event0"
[     2.961] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[     2.961] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     2.961] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     2.961] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     2.962] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event5)
[     2.962] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     2.962] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     2.962] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Dell WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event9)
[     2.962] (**) Dell WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     2.962] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Dell WMI hotkeys'
[     2.962] (**) Dell WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[     2.962] (**) evdev: Dell WMI hotkeys: Device: "/dev/input/event9"
[     2.962] (--) evdev: Dell WMI hotkeys: Vendor 0 Product 0
[     2.962] (--) evdev: Dell WMI hotkeys: Found keys
[     2.962] (II) evdev: Dell WMI hotkeys: Configuring as keyboard
[     2.962] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input11/event9"
[     2.962] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Dell WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[     2.962] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     2.962] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     2.962] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     2.965] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Integrated_Webcam_HD (/dev/input/event15)
[     2.965] (**) Integrated_Webcam_HD: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     2.965] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Integrated_Webcam_HD'
[     2.965] (**) Integrated_Webcam_HD: always reports core events
[     2.965] (**) evdev: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Device: "/dev/input/event15"
[     2.965] (--) evdev: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Vendor 0xc45 Product 0x670c
[     2.965] (--) evdev: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Found keys
[     2.965] (II) evdev: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Configuring as keyboard
[     2.965] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-5/2-5:1.0/input/input19/event15"
[     2.965] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Integrated_Webcam_HD" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[     2.965] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     2.965] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     2.965] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     2.965] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[     2.965] (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
[     2.965] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ELAN Touchscreen (/dev/input/event14)
[     2.965] (**) ELAN Touchscreen: Applying InputClass "evdev touchscreen catchall"
[     2.965] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'ELAN Touchscreen'
[     2.965] (**) ELAN Touchscreen: always reports core events
[     2.965] (**) evdev: ELAN Touchscreen: Device: "/dev/input/event14"
[     3.022] (--) evdev: ELAN Touchscreen: Vendor 0x4f3 Product 0x20d0
[     3.022] (--) evdev: ELAN Touchscreen: Found absolute axes
[     3.022] (--) evdev: ELAN Touchscreen: Found absolute multitouch axes
[     3.022] (II) evdev: ELAN Touchscreen: No buttons found, faking one.
[     3.022] (--) evdev: ELAN Touchscreen: Found x and y absolute axes
[     3.022] (--) evdev: ELAN Touchscreen: Found absolute touchscreen
[     3.022] (II) evdev: ELAN Touchscreen: Configuring as touchscreen
[     3.022] (**) evdev: ELAN Touchscreen: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[     3.022] (**) evdev: ELAN Touchscreen: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[     3.022] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/0003:04F3:20D0.0002/input/input17/event14"
[     3.022] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ELAN Touchscreen" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 14)
[     3.022] (II) evdev: ELAN Touchscreen: initialized for absolute axes.
[     3.022] (**) ELAN Touchscreen: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[     3.022] (**) ELAN Touchscreen: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[     3.022] (**) ELAN Touchscreen: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     3.022] (**) ELAN Touchscreen: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     9.093] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SHP", prod id 5153
[     9.093] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[     9.093] (II) intel(0): Modeline "3200x1800"x0.0  373.25  3200 3248 3280 3360  1800 1803 1808 1852 -hsync -vsync (111.1 kHz eP)
```

### Edit:

It is getting interesting. There is nothing in syslog, Xorg.log, glass.log, journalctl. When it happens, everything seems quiet. Where else could I look?

Comment: The screen turns back on when you close and reopen the lid?

Comment: Yes. Though sometimes (especially if I closed the lid because of one of those blank screens) it turns black again after ~5 seconds.

Comment: I had a similar issue (screen wouldn't wake up after going to sleep) and managed to work around it by assigning an `xargs` command that switched the screen off and back on again to a keyboard shortcut. That might be slightly more practical than closing the lid. Also, have you checked for an updated version of the intel driver?

Comment: I've read about a few workarounds using `xrandr` to achieve the same, though it feels more like a hack. I guess I'll go with that for the moment, though I'm sure there's some way to investigate the problem, I just don't know which one yet. As for the driver, I'm running an up-to-date testing, so it should be good.